# AppFabric LocalCache - Least Used Eviction

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

If I am caching something in local cache and using it on a regular basis does the distributed cache know that the local cache is using it?

The reason I ask this is because the distributed cache has a Least Used Eviction policy.  If I am not using it from distributed cache and the distributed cache doesn't know I am using it then it will be evicted at some stage.

This is a large piece of data that rarely changes so I will cache it for a long period of time.  I don't want to have to drag 2 or 3 MG across the wire more often than I have to based on it being evicted from the Distributed Cache on a least used basis.

Hence my question - does the distributed cache have knowledge that it is being used and therefore not evict it as least used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting.

The documentation says that when an object is requested from the cache, if it exists in the local cache then

> the reference to the object is returned immediately without contacting
>   the server
>   ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790983.aspx))

in which case, the remote cache cannot possibly be notified that the object is being used, and this would seem to support your thought that the object could become a candidate for eviction.

There's some discussion [here](http://www.suneet.net/FrmBlogViewer.aspx?blogid=70) that suggests the local cache also uses an LRU algorithm, and I'd be interested to know whether the two caches do any communication/synchronisation of their LRU timings.